# ignore some .py in module

Tags: python, module, package

say I have following python module:

```
foo\\
  __init__.py
  bar.py
  ignoreme.py
```

how can I make `foo.ignoreme` is not imported when importing `foo`? I can make ignoreme into a submodule(which is not automatically imported), but that doesn't seem like a simple solution. also I don't want to/can't write `__all__` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: I believe you are out of luck. __all__ is for exactly this use case. May I ask why you can't use it?

Comment: Ah, there is another solution of course: never do "import foo", just do "from foo import something"

Comment: Unless you explicitly import ignoreme in \_\_init\_\_, importing foo *already* isn't imported when you import foo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing foo won't import ignoreme.py anyway.  Only "import foo.ignoreme" will execute ignoreme.py.